# If you come early to a minyan factory and catch the previous minyan's torah reading, are you yotzeh?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, tzibur-community

If you come early to your minyan in a minyan factory for shachrit and you're able to hear the entire torah reading from beginning to end, do you have to stick around for YOUR minyan's torah reading the second time around?

IE: 
 Your Shachris starts at 8:00 am.
 You arrive at 7:45 am. 
 The previous minyan just took out the torah scroll.

Can you pay attention to the previous minyan's torah reading and leave right after shemonah esrei or do you have to listen to your own and stay until the end of the shachrit of your own minyan?

Comment: Are you _yotzeh_ for what? AFAIK there's no personal obligation to hear the Torah reading. What about _ashrei_, _aleinu_, etc.?

Comment: @Daniel, you can say ashrei and aleinu with the first minyan. Your prayer order is just flipped around, but you say all the same things.

Comment: @AniYodea Flipping the order of that stuff around seems a lot more problematic to me than missing the Torah reading.

Comment: Probably best to say karbanos or learn some torah instead... But I figured since you're already there, why not take advantage of the situation?

Comment: I don't think you can flip around the order of prayer, which was established by Hazal and has a deep foundation. Exceptions are made for skipping parts of e.g., psukei dezimra to sync shmonei esrei with the mynian, and catching up later.

But if you catch an earlier kriat haTorah, you cannot say ashrei/aleinu with them and be yotzei for the next minyan. What you could do theoretically is to say ashrei/aleinu on your own in your minyan and leave during kriat haTorah. But CYLOR because this cannot be routine practice